# How to send smtp mail in python with default network credentials?

Tags: python, smtp

How to send smtp mail in python with default network credentials?

In C# we do something like this:

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient(MailParameters.SmtpMailServer, 25))
{
     smtp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
     smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Did a bit a googling but couldn't find the equivalent in python. Any help would be appreciated.